# Cross Platform Blank App Xamarin Project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create an app using Visual Studio and Xamarin that will be cross platform. I've been trying to follow a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdOpmFzj4JY) I found online to do this.

When the guy in the video went to create a new project, he had the below screen, and created a `Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable`
[image]

I've installed the necessary components (Xamarin, WPF and a couple of others) with the IDE, however I don't see this option.
[image]

I've created a project using `Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)` but it doesn't have the same structure as the desired template. Am I missing a component? Is the template called something different now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video is almost two years old, which means that some parts look different today.

If you click on the create a new `xamarin.forms` app, you will come to a new step where you can choose a blank app.

Then you have a choice, either choose shared projects or .net (portable).

The .net will give you a portable class library, like that in the video.
The two methods have different advantages.

[image]

Read more in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing

I hope the information will help you!

Comment: PCLs have been replaced for .NET Standard, as shown on the picture you shared

Comment: I've done this and it's created `MyApp.Android`, `MyApp.iOS` and `MyApp.UWP`, but it doesn't have the `.Portable` solution with the `App.cs` class?

Comment: @David, As mention in comment PCL are replced by .NET standards. So, your solution doesn't contains Portable class library. Instead of that you can see simple class library which uses .Net Standard.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar so which class does the code go in for it to be cross-platform?

Comment: You can see three projects, i.e. your name of solution, another is name of solution with android and last one is solution name with ios. If  you haven't selected uwp. Then you have to write your cross-platform code in simple project which name is same as the solution name. No android or iOS.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Yes I have `MyApp` with a C# icon next to it, which contains `Dependencies`, `App.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml` - do you mean I have to add the classes into here manually, then when compiling it will compile them to `.Android` and `.iOS`?

Comment: Exactly. And if you want simple app then change your template from blank to Master Details and you will understand better.